# How do I go about reading a text file (like a .log) that is constantly updated? Is this called a stream?

Tags: c, stream

I'm making a program in C that will read a log file and constantly look for a certain string. It isn't complete obviously. Right now, i have it where it will get a number of all the lines in the .log, start at a certain line number from a .txt file, and go to EOF or until it finds a certain string. Further down the road, if i do it this way, i would have to constantly update my line number in the text file for a starting point.

I'm told there's a way to have my program read the "stream" of the .log while looking for a certain string and then i can get it to do what i want. How do i go about doing this? I'm not very advanced so comments and explanations of methods are greatly appreciated. Forgive my coding if it is a little messy. Will definitely fix it up once I'm able to get what I want in it's final form.

I need a better understanding and explanation than the question that is apparently the same as another that has been asked before.

```
    #define MAX_LENGTH 500
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> //for exit();
    #include <string.h>


    int main() {
        char errorCheck[MAX_LENGTH] = {"ERROR: Problem Accessing System Db! - bIsRunning, 1"}; //this will be the string the program searches for.
        char ec_processLog[MAX_LENGTH];
        char oldLineNumberFile[MAX_LENGTH]; //might change
        long int newLineNumberFile[MAX_LENGTH]; //might change
        long int oldLineNumber, newLineNumber;
        char line[MAX_LENGTH];
        int resultOfCompare, lineCount = 1, found = 0;

        FILE *fp1; //used to open ec_process.log
        FILE *fp2; //used as our line starting point
        FILE *fp3; //will be our error log file
        fp1 = fopen("C:/Script testing/ec_process.log", "r");
        fp2 = fopen("C:/Script testing/Fix/lineNumber.txt", "r");
        fp3 = fopen("C:/Script testing/Fix/returnityFixErrors.txt", "w");

        if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL) {
            fprintf(fp3, "ERROR with ec_process.log file and/or lineNumber file");
            exit(1);
        }


        while (fgets(oldLineNumberFile, sizeof oldLineNumberFile, fp2)) {

            oldLineNumber = atoi(oldLineNumberFile);  //atoi() converts string to integer
        }

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp1) != NULL) { //This lets me go line by line in a file, reading each line one-by-one
            //In doing so, i can use a IF loop to where once my line++ goes to a certain number, that's where i will start my
            //FOR loop
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';  // Lop off potential \n


            if (lineCount >= oldLineNumber) {

                resultOfCompare = strcmp(errorCheck, line);

                if (resultOfCompare == 0) {
                    printf("FOUND %s\n ON LINE: %ld", line, lineCount);
                    found++;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    lineCount++;
                    continue;
                }

            }else {
                lineCount++;
            }

        }


        getchar();
        getchar();

        return 0;

    }
```